# QuillJS Custom blot selection: how to implement index and position

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, quill

I am creating some custom blots in QuillJS. They mostly work, however I am having an issue with copy and paste of the blot and think it is due to not providing a `index(node: Node, offset: number): number` or `position(index: number, inclusive: boolean): [Node, number]` implementation.

The blots are of type `blots/embed`. And they generate markup that looks something like (I add a `sample` and `spellcheck` attribute, and generate content that contains an icon and some text):

`<sfx sample="A Sample" spellcheck="false">
&#65279;
<span contenteditable="false"><i class="btr bt-volume-up"></i>A Sample</span>
&#65279;
</sfx>`

If I attempt to select the blot on its own and then copy and paste I only get the content of the sfx tag pasted, not a new embed instance...(the top embed is the expected format and the bottom is what it looks like when pasted. The blue border is showing selection).

[image]

If I select the blot and include anything else in the selection e.g. a space to the left side, the copy/ paste works as expected.

[image]

I do want the default selection behavior i.e. the embed selects as a whole and behaves like it has length of 1.

I'm having trouble working out what to do in `index` and `position` (assuming that is the cause?) to make this work. Can anybody help by describing what I need to do and an explanation of how these callbacks are expected to behave (the description in the parchment docs is a little thin). A reference implementation that does something similar would suffice, I've looked at the embeds built into quill but they don't seem to help.

Comment: hey, any progress on that? I've got the same problem right now

Comment: @alabama no sorry haven’t solved it

Comment: I'm having the same problem too. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Ruchi no haven’t found a solution

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution on the page below.
In my case the code below, could find and delete my custom blot and leave everything else intact.

The **node_of_custom_blot is a normal javascript object** what you can **find with** **getElementById** , **getElementsByTagName**,**getElementsByClassName** , etc... or **create with** **document.createElement or super.create()** from the custom blots class.

https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/1115

```
...
let blot = Quill.find( node_of_custom_blot );
let index = blot.offset(quill.scroll);
var Delta = Quill.import('delta');
quill.updateContents(new Delta()
    .retain(index)  
    .delete(1)                  
      
);
...
```